# Capturing program debug event messages

Tags: python, windows, event-log

I'm trying to capture a debug event message from an in-house developed application using Python.  I have looked at using `win32event` and other features in PyWin32.

The process will be launched with python, I have been using `subprocess.popen()` to do this.

I have been researching and testing different methods to do this since Monday, I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I'm just missing it.  Any help, suggestions, or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: the aplication is written in python? or just the capturing program?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by a "debug event message"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to capture STDERR?

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open('C:\\error_log.txt', 'w')
```